# What font is used in the bambu logo?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I received the logo attached and I need to know the font used on it.

I searched on Fontsquirel's Matcherator and myfonts' WhatTheFont that I think are the best font finders, and the closest font I found was Bilbao Sans font which is not the exact one but it's not too far.

I also used Font finder extension of Firefox on their website http://www.bambu.life/ and it indicates Ubuntu font but it's not the right font.

Could anyone tell me what font it is?

[image]

Comment: Looks more like a horribly drawn hand lettering. On the plus side, it should take you 2 minutes to redraw that. Just a bunch of half circle segments connected to vertcial lines.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: It's not a font. Some font with nearly fitting u and m is taken and the text is modified as an image. If one takes Pero Light, squeeze it slightly vertically and make b and a from o by adding a line taken from u, a good replicate is got.

Pero Light also has nearly right b, but the flat top must be made curved. Character a is totally different in Pero Light.

Answer (score 0):

The "a" is not the same, but this could be a slightly modified "[Y2K Neophite](https://www.dafont.com/y2k-neophyte.font?text=bambu)"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it it's [Maxwell Light](http://www.1001fonts.com/maxwell-font.html)

[image]

Comment: Well done. Maybe you can reveal how did you find it.

Comment: Please add at the very least a screenshot of Maxell Light, so we can compare and verify you're right. While you're at it, please also add a link to a place where we can acquire the typeface for download. Thanks.